# Disable services state remembering at Windows 10

Tags: windows, service, admin

I have WMware installed. But I don't use it often so I open Services, stop all WMware services and set start type for them as manual. So after restart windows all this services are stopped. When I need WMvare I just go to services and start them. This approach worked fine untill I upgraded to Windows 10. At Win 10 after restarting system MWware services works if they was working before restart. If I stop services before restart they will not work after restart. So I think Win10 somehow remember last service state and restore it after restart. This is not about WMware services only. Other services behaves the same way. So my question is there some way disable remembering last service state after restart at Windows 10?

Comment: Does the Startup Type actually change back to what it was before the restart or does the service simply start? Also, Windows can still trigger a service to start in Manual mode, it's just not seen very often

Comment: @Crimsonfox  Start type is Manual after restarting, but services are running.

Comment: Is it possible that there's VMWare apps that begin in startup that are triggering them? Though it's still odd that it's happening with other services but I don't have a WIn10 device around to test. You could disable the services and use a BAT to enable and start the services when you need them.

Comment: @Crimsonfox Yes I can use bat file for WM services but still there are other services that behaves the same way.

Comment: What version of VMware are you running?  You need to be running at least VMware Workstation Pro 12.x when using on Windows 10 as the host platform (per https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=2129859).  Besides that, boot into Safe Mode and see if you can manually start the VMware service.  If you can start VMware in Safe Mode, but not in normal mode, then its not Windows 10 issue but a driver or 3rd-party software causing the issue, and I would look to upgrade VMware if you are not at 12.x.

Comment: @T Heron I have no problems with starting WM services.

Comment: Gotcha, but what _version_ of VMware are you running?

Comment: @T Heron 12.0.0

Answer (score -1):

Startup Type" for Service
Automatic - With a service in this state, it will start at boot time. Some services, when no longer required, will also automatically stop when not needed. If you find you do not need a service, place it into Manual or Disabled.
Automatic (Delayed Start) - With a service in this state, it will start just after boot time. Some services, when no longer required, will also automatically stop when not needed. If you find you do not need a service, place it into Manual or Disabled.
Automatic (Delayed Start, Trigger Start) - With a service in this state, it will start just after boot when specifically called.
Manual (Trigger Start) - This is a version of Manual mode that allows Windows to start a service when specifically called and Microsoft’s answer to “too many services running all the time”.
Manual - Manual mode allows Windows to start a service when needed. However, very few services will start up when required in Manual mode. If you find you need a service, place it into Automatic.
Disabled - This setting will stop a service from starting, even if needed. Errors in the Event Viewer will show up complaining of that fact. Some services, while Disabled, will constantly complain. However, this situation is taken care of if placed in Manual. The service descriptions identifies those that should be in Manual vice Disabled.

Comment: This is not what I am asking about.